# No aligned properly inline-flex

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a list with some item in it but the last item is not aligned properly. I want it to properly align on the same line.

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<ul class="items-center">
        <li class="inline-flex items-center">
            <img
                    src="~/static/img/products/mktpoint/sm/authentic.svg"
                    alt="100% Authentic"
            />
            {{ $t('header.100%Authentic') }}
        </li>
        <li class="inline-flex items-center">
            <img
                    src="~/static/img/products/mktpoint/sm/return.svg"
                    alt="14 Days Return"
            />
            {{ $t('header.14DaysReturn') }}
        </li>
        <li class="inline-flex items-center">
            <img
                    class="mr-3"
                    src="~/static/img/products/mktpoint/sm/shipping.svg"
                    alt="Free Shipping"
            />
            {{ $t('header.freeShipping') }}
        </li>
        <li class="inline-flex link-black-line items-center">
            <button v-b-modal.modal-marketing>{{ $t('product.showDetails') }}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And here is my css code

```
.inline-flex {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.link-black-line {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    color: #222;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre], that reproduces what your screenshot shows. What you have currently given, really doesn’t: https://jsfiddle.net/4L51o82n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.items-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If you want to space each child element at equal distances, horizontally, you can add `justify-content: space-between`

Edit: My solution did not work for OP. This is the one that worked for him: `flex: 1 1 auto;` You can find more in comments.

Comment: trying adding it to the `<ul>` tag instead of `<li>`

Comment: Or please share code that includes the parent div and the ul tag.

Comment: i updated my question and im using bootsrap-vue

Comment: Try it on items-center and see. I don't use bootstrap or vue. But, good old CSS this does the trick for me.

Comment: Also, please let me know if its not working. I'll withdraw the answer. It can be that the bootstrap styles are probably overriding your custom styles.

Comment: i added `flex: 1 1 auto;` and now all good, thanks for you answer too